# 7z executable in SSIS

Tags: ssis, 7zip

How do I implement an execute process task to extract all files in a directory using 7z. exe in SSIS ?

I am trying to unzip all files in a certain directory using 7z executable but it gives a process error code 2.

Comment: How do you have your `Execute Process Task` defined currently?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are specifying a WorkingDirectory rather than specifying the full path for the file in the arguments.

Comment: Working Directory is directory where zip files are. Arguments is e destination directory -aoa

Comment: Your arguments should be e <compressed file> -o<destination directory> note the lack of a space between -o and the destination. So to unzip all files you'd use e *.zip -oC:\foldertoextractto